# JTree Not Refreshing after Cell Edit

Tags: java, jtree

I am having an issue with the itemTree.stopEditing() in the code below.

I can edit the device fine. The edit changes Node text from just an IP address to beIP address + Hostname (making the string longer). The problem is, after the edit, the JTree displays IP followed by "..."

It seems like the Tree is not updating its UI. I thought using the Editing functions of a Tree would update the UI automatically? How can I fix?

```
this.setShowsRootHandles(true);
this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("\n[MyItemTree]mousePressed");
        MyItemTree itemTree = (MyItemTree) e.getSource();
        TreePath tp = itemTree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        Rectangle pathBounds = itemTree.getUI().getPathBounds(itemTree, tp);
        TreePath[] selectionPaths = itemTree.getSelectionPaths();//what if this is empty?
        Object lastPathComponent = tp.getLastPathComponent();// what if this is empty?
        digOutNodesForSelection((DefaultMutableTreeNode) lastPathComponent, itemTree);
        itemTree.setEditable(true);

        ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectionPaths.length; i++) {
            Object lastPathComponent1 = selectionPaths[i].getLastPathComponent();
            //Should only be adding the Leaf Nodes here
            if (lastPathComponent1 instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                nodes.add((DefaultMutableTreeNode) lastPathComponent1);
            }

        }
        try {
            DeviceEditor deviceEditor = new DeviceEditor(nodes);
            itemTree.setCellEditor(deviceEditor);
            deviceEditor.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                    // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
                    itemTree.cancelEditing();
                }
            });
            //add an actionListener to the deviceEditor for the cancel and update buttons
            deviceEditor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    System.out.println("ACTION COMMAND= " + ae.getActionCommand());
                    if ("Update".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
                        //get the Device From the editor.
                        //update all the nodes' userObjects to the values of the editor except the ones with <Multiple Values>
                        //stopEditing expects an Object from DeviceEditor. We need a way to stopEditing without providing an object. 
                        itemTree.stopEditing(); //update the nodes     

                    }
                    if ("Cancel".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
                        itemTree.cancelEditing();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        }

        //   }
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
            System.out.println("Right Mouse Button");
            JPopupMenu itemMenu = new JPopupMenu();
            {
                JMenuItem deleteItem = new JMenuItem("Delete");
                {
                    deleteItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                            System.out.println("[MyItemTree]actionPerformed.deleteDevice");
                            TreePath[] selectionPaths = MyItemTree.this.getSelectionPaths();
                            System.out.println("[MyItemTree]SelectionPaths.length= " + selectionPaths.length);
                            for (TreePath path : selectionPaths) {
                                System.out.println("Here");
                                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
                                Object userObject = node.getUserObject();
                                if (userObject instanceof MyItemTreeInterface) {
                                    DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) MyItemTree.this.getModel();
                                    //model.nodeChanged(node);
                                    DeviceCollection collection = (DeviceCollection) MyItemTree.this.collectionTreeInterface.getCollection();
                                    System.out.println("Collection size before= " + collection.size());
                                    collection.remove((DefaultDevice) userObject);
                                    model.removeNodeFromParent(node);
                                    System.out.println("Collection size after= " + collection.size());
                                    MyItemTree.this.filter();

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                JMenuItem addMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Add");
                itemMenu.add(addMenuItem);
                itemMenu.add(deleteItem);
                itemMenu.add(COPY_MENUITEM);
                itemMenu.add(CUT_MENUITEM);
            }

            if (pathBounds != null && pathBounds.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                EDIT_MENUITEM.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        //if a DefaultDevice cell was selected...                               
                        itemTree.startEditingAtPath(tp);
                    }
                });
                itemMenu.insert(EDIT_MENUITEM, 0);
                itemMenu.addSeparator();
                //build device popupmenu.
                System.out.println("MENUITEMS= " + MyItemTreeInterface.MENUITEMS.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < MyItemTreeInterface.MENUITEMS.size(); i++) {
                    itemMenu.add(MyItemTreeInterface.MENUITEMS.get(i));
                }
                itemMenu.show(itemTree, e.getX(), e.getY());//construct the popup and show. 
                System.out.println("number of selected paths= " + selectionPaths.length);

            } else {
                //Show the right click menu for the tree   
                System.out.println("[MyItemTree]rightButton on Tree");
                itemTree.addMenusToPopup(collectionTreeInterface.getTreeMenu()).show(itemTree, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }

        }//end right click
        if (SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(e)) {
            System.out.println("[MyItemTree]middleButton");
            if (pathBounds != null && pathBounds.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                //Show middle click menu for Device
            } else {
                //Show middle click menu for Tree
            }
        }

    }
});
```

DigoutNodes

```
private void digOutNodesForSelection(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, MyItemTree itemTree) {
    System.out.println("DIG");
    if (!node.isLeaf()) {
        System.out.println("Node is not a Leaf");
        int childCount = node.getChildCount();
        System.out.println("Child Count= " + childCount);
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) itemTree.getModel();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode tempNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getChildAt(i);
            TreeNode[] pathToRoot = model.getPathToRoot(tempNode);
            itemTree.getSelectionModel().addSelectionPath(new TreePath(pathToRoot));
            if (tempNode.getChildCount() != 0) {
                //Dig this node
                System.out.println("Has Children, dig More...");
                digOutNodesForSelection(tempNode, itemTree);
            }

        }
        // System.out.println("SelectionPaths= " + itemTree.getSelectionPaths());
    }

}
```

CollectionTreeInterface

```
public static interface CollectionTreeInterface<N> {

    public TreeSet<SelectableFilterItem> getFilters();

    public ArrayList<JMenuItem> getTreeMenu();

    public ArrayList<JMenuItem> getDeviceMenu(Collection<N> c);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener o);

    //  public Iterator iterator();
    public TreeCellEditor getTreeCellEditor();

    public TreeCellRenderer getTreeCellRenderer();

    public Collection getCollection();

}
```

DeviceEdiotr implements TreeCellEditor. Here are the methods as they are implemented

```
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree jtree, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
        // this.tree = jtree;
        return this;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = this.nodes.get(0);
        return (DefaultDevice) node.getUserObject();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject eo) {
        //should be true only if it's a leaf. 
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject eo) {
        //Don't Select
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        try {
            System.out.println("\n [DeviceEditor] stopCellEditing()");
            if (!this.addressField.getText().equals(DefaultDevice.MULTIVALUE)) {
                multiValueDevice.setAddress(this.addressField.getText());
            }
            multiValueDevice.setHostName(this.hostNameField.getText());
            multiValueDevice.setDeviceType(this.deviceTypeField.getText());
            multiValueDevice.setLocation(this.locationField.getText());
            multiValueDevice.setSerialNumber(this.serialField.getText());
            multiValueDevice.setVendor(this.vendorField.getText());
            multiValueDevice.setModel(this.modelField.getText());
            multiValueDevice.setOS(this.osField.getText());
            multiValueDevice.setDescription(this.descriptionField.getText());
            multiValueDevice.setVersion(this.versionField.getText());
            multiValueDevice.setDeviceType(this.deviceTypeField.getText());
//            //Update Connect           
            multiValueDevice.setSelectedProtocol(this.currentProtocol);
            //Update Display
            multiValueDevice.setDisplayHostName(this.hostNameCheckBox.isSelected());
            multiValueDevice.setDisplayIPV4Address(this.ipV4checkBox.isSelected());
            multiValueDevice.setDisplayIPV6Address(this.ipV6CheckBox.isSelected());

            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
            Collection<Future<DefaultDevice>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterator<DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodeC = nodes.iterator();
            while (nodeC.hasNext()) {
                //create Runnables for each nodeDevice to update it.
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = nodeC.next();
                DefaultDevice nodeDevice = (DefaultDevice) node.getUserObject();
                //update the node
                futures.add((Future<DefaultDevice>) pool.submit(new UPDATE_RUNNABLE(nodeDevice, multiValueDevice)));
                // SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new UPDATE_RUNNABLE(nodeDevice, editorDevice));

            }

            //  DeviceEditor.UPDATE_DEVICES(nodes, multiValueDevice);
            System.out.println("futures= " + futures.size());
            for (Future<?> future : futures) {
                try {
                    DefaultDevice get = (DefaultDevice) future.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Exception 1");
                    return false;
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Exception 2");
                    return false;
                }

            }
            return true;//only return true when all the tasks have been completed. 
        } catch (IPConverter.InvalidIPException ex) {
            Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void cancelCellEditing() {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener cl) {
        this.cellListeners.add(cl);

    }

    @Override
    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener cl) {
        this.cellListeners.remove(cl);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `DeviceEditor`, `DeviceCollection`, and the methods `collectionTreeInterface` and `digOutNodesForSelection`?  This would give enough of your code to execute it and test it out.

Comment: I'm new to this, where is a good place to post all the code?

Comment: No problem, just edit your question and create a separate code block for each one.  A code block is a sequence of lines indented by 4 spaces.  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I posted what I could fit that was relevant. If you need more let me know.